# Does Vala provide something like C++ friend classes?

Tags: vala

With C++ I like unit test functions or classes to be *friends* of the classes they test. That way I am not limited to the public interface. I need less mocking or boilerplate to test all methods. At the same time separating public and private methods.

With Vala is made most methods public to be able to test them. This exposes too much of the class interface.

Is there a way to make unit tests (classes or functions) *friends* like in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked in [this](https://matrix.to/#/!vZJkZtjCbdoBxnHjhf:matrix.org?via=gnome.org&via=matrix.org&via=librem.one) Vala chat(you can try it). The short answer seems to be no. There is a dead framework for testing [ValaDate](https://github.com/chebizarro/valadate).

Comment: I avoid the chat as answers and questions there are not saved anywhere and impossible to find for others. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Documentation#Places_to_discuss_and_ask_questions Here I posted all the links where you can ask questions about the vala. The gnome's discus is another great option.